# Cache and Save All Image Conten In WebView From Url And Load It

Tags: android, image, caching, webview

I have Web Application runs in Android. I can cache my web, so if user has not internet connection, he can still access web from cache. **But it only run when user has not Internet Connection**.

Now, for optimzing my apps, **when user has internet connection**, I want to cache all image that show in `WebView` And store it locally/cache it, and when user open a page with same src image that I have cached it, it load from local, not load it from web again. Or May be not image, but `html` page that visited cache it, and when user back to url page again, `Webview` load it from local, not from internet.

I have search the code for two days but still no finding solution.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
private void enableWVCache() {

      webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

      // Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
      webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);

      File dir = getCacheDir();
      if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
         }
      webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(dir.getPath());
      webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
      webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

      webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
}
```

and then

```
if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
```

}

and the method `isNetworkAvailable()` checks for an active network connection:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Finally, don't forget to add the following three permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Thankyou, but does it cache all page? I just want to cache image only.

Comment: @MukhlisSaputro it caches the whole page.